# Laravel and Kendo UI Grid: Routing url to request in Grid Editing function CRUD json

Tags: laravel, kendo-grid, crud

I want to use the Kendo UI in Laravel. It is work good, while I dont want to make a CRUD things with it. In the Telerik UI (Kendo) package contains working examples with PHP wrappers the CRUD functions, but I can't implement it with Laravel framework correctly. (Show only the empty grid.) In the 1st section of the controller, make a json content when the request is 'POST' and depends on the parameter make some CRUD stuff. The 2nd section create the grid and the back DataSourceTransport (etc.), and the urls which is called the 'POST' request. The route call the 'any' route (route\web.php), but not works correctly. I imagine the route settings is bad, but i dont know what is the solution. (I signed "//!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" the questionaire section)

GjtorzsXController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

    class GjtorzsXController extends Controller
    {
        //
        public function index()
        {
            $result = new \DataSourceResult('sqlite:../database/database.sqlite');//
            //1st section----------------------------------------------------------
             if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {        
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            $request = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
            $type = $_GET['type'];
            $columns = array('Rendszam', 'Tipus');
            switch($type) {
                case 'create':
                    $result = $result->create('gepjarmu', $columns, $request->models, 'id');
                    break;
                case 'read':
                    $result = $result->read('gepjarmu', $columns, $request);
                    break;
                case 'update':
                    $result = $result->update('gepjarmu', $columns, $request->models, 'id');
                    break;
                case 'destroy':
                    $result = $result->destroy('gepjarmu', $request->models, 'id');
                    break;
            }
            echo json_encode($result);
            exit;
            }

            //2nd section------------------------------------------------------
            $transport = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransport();
            $create = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportCreate();
            $create->url('gjtorzsx?type=create')
                   ->contentType('application/json')
                   ->type('POST');
            $read = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportRead();
            $read->url('gjtorzsx?type=read') //TestPage.php?type=read   gjtorzsx?type=read
                 ->contentType('application/json')
                 ->type('POST');
            $update = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportUpdate();

    //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    //This url is not correct??????????????????????
            $update->url('gjtorzsx?type=update') //????????????????????????????
                   ->contentType('application/json')
                   ->type('POST');

            $destroy = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceTransportDestroy();
            $destroy->url('gjtorzsx?type=destroy')
                    ->contentType('application/json')
                    ->type('POST');

            $transport->create($create)
                      ->read($read)
                      ->update($update)
                      ->destroy($destroy)
                      ->parameterMap('function(data) {
                          return kendo.stringify(data);
                      }');

            $model = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModel();


            $rendszamField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('Rendszam');
            $rendszamField->type('string');

            $tipusField = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchemaModelField('Tipus');
            $tipusField->type('string');

            $model->id('id')
                  ->addField($rendszamField)
                  ->addField($tipusField;

            $schema = new \Kendo\Data\DataSourceSchema();
            $schema->data('data')
                   ->errors('errors')
                   ->model($model)
                       ->total('total');

            $dataSource = new \Kendo\Data\DataSource();
            $dataSource->transport($transport)
                       ->batch(true)
                       ->pageSize(30)
                       ->schema($schema);

            $grid = new \Kendo\UI\Grid('grid');

            $rendszamColumn = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
            $rendszamColumn->field('Rendszam')
                           ->title('Rendszám')
                           ->width(100);

            $tipusColumn = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
            $tipusColumn->field('Tipus')
                        ->title('Típus')
                        ->width(200);        

            $command = new \Kendo\UI\GridColumn();
            $command->addCommandItem('destroy')
                    ->title(' ')
                    ->width(150);

            $grid->addColumn($rendszamColumn, $tipusColumn, $command)
                 ->dataSource($dataSource)
                 ->addToolbarItem(new \Kendo\UI\GridToolbarItem('create'),
                   new \Kendo\UI\GridToolbarItem('save'), new \Kendo\UI\GridToolbarItem('cancel'))
                 ->height(540)
                 ->navigatable(true)
                 ->editable(true)
                 ->groupable(true)
                 ->pageable(true);

            $args = array('grid' => $grid);
            return \View::make('hello2')->with($args);
        }
    }
```

route\web.php:

```
Route::any('gjtorzsx', 'GjtorzsXController@index');
```

helo2.blade.php:
    ...
          {!! $grid->render() !!}
    ...

Comment: Any error messages? Check your logs. Can you trim this down to a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please?

Comment: There is no error messages, only the grid is empty. I check the log and the error is in the route url: 'TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68' I try the solution: '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">' but not works...

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this VerifyCsrfToken exception.  The information from this link was very helpful:
http://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2015-laravel5-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken/?page=3)
,looking under the response by geethpw.  Specifically, I made the following additions:

In my meta-tags at the top of my HTML documents, I added

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And then I added the following script in my headers after the jQuery declaration:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
</script>
```

I did not add the CSRF token as a hidden field since the grid is not declared in the context of a form.

I also saw your comment on Laracasts since it seems like we were struggling with the same issues.  I would note that I handled the DataSource a little differently than you did; if you run into any problems with this let me know and I'll post what I ended up doing.  I'm finally getting my data to display, although I haven't started implementing the other CRUD actions.